# Loading Silverlight UserControls dynamically

Tags: silverlight, architecture

Im making a silverlight 5 application where i need to provide a kind of plugin architecture. Its for a dashboard like program, where different "presentations" can be plugged in. I have a simple data source but need to make it possible to plugin different user controls for each user using the system. Eg. Version one of the system has bar chart and line chart. Version two has bar chart, line chart and now a pie chart. I would like to make my solution so that i dont have to build the entire silverlight application each time. So that i can simply "plug in" a new chart type.

Are there any way of building this plugin like functionality in Silverlight? Its OK if thesilverlight client downloads stuff when it starts, this , i imagine is only done when things has changed (a plugin)

Answer (score 0):

H dude,

you should check out prism.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943055.aspx